# Integral of $f$ and $g$ equal for all intervals containing positive and negative numbers sufficient condition for $f=g$?

Tags: calculus

Is there a way to get from $$\int_a^b \delta(t)dt=-\int_a^bt  \frac{d (\delta (t))} {dt} dt$$
for all $$(a,b):(a<0) \land (b>0) \land a,b\in\Re $$
to $$\delta (x)=t \frac {d (\delta (x))} {dx}\space \forall x \in \Re ?$$
Here, $\delta$ is the Dirac Delta distribution (this is a physics problem in disguise).

Comment: Do they have to be continuous functions? Otherwise $f(x)=\begin{cases}1&&\text{if }x=0\\0&&\text{if }x\neq 0\end{cases}$ and $g(x)=0$ form a counterexample.

Comment: That's a good point. Maybe I should edit the example because it's trickier than that. (No they're not continuous but they also aren't functions.)

Comment: You could ask if this implies $f=g$ almost everywhere (*i.e.,* off a set of measure zero). Also, your question is equivalent to asking if $$\int_a^b f(x)\;dx=0$$ for all such intervals implies that $f\equiv 0$.

Answer (score 1):

These two are not *truly* functions, so it doesn't make sense to compare their values pointwise. What does make sense is to compare them as *distributions*. What you should be doing is asking if

$$\int_a^b f(t)\delta(t)\,dt = -\int_a^b f(t)t\delta'(t)\,dt$$

for all functions $f\in \mathcal{S}(\Bbb R)$ (the Schwartz space of functions). The left hand side evaluates to $f(0)$ since $a < 0 < b$. The right hand side we can evaluate by "integration by parts." Note that since $\delta(t)$ isn't actually a function, we can't "integrate" it, per se, but we can extend differentiation to distributions by just pushing the derivative onto the function. Doing so, we have

$$\int_a^b tf(t)\delta'(t)\,dt = -\int_a^b (tf(t))'\delta(t)\,dt = -\int_a^b (f(t)+tf'(t))\delta(t)\,dt. $$

This equals $-f(0)-0\cdot f'(0) = -f(0)$ since, again, $a < 0 < b$. Thus we see that, indeed, $\delta(t) = -t\delta'(t)$ as distributions.